# Using Gulp how to first compile Typescript then concatenate the result and uglify it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, tsc, gulp-typescript

I'm working on a project using `Typescript` currently I'm facing a problem compiling `Typescript` and then concatenate the result using `Gulp`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('vendor/**/*.js')
        // I want to add ts files then combile and concat
        .gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            out: 'output.js'
        }))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify());
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

In words what I need to do is:

1. Get the external `JavaScript` libraries.
2. Get `Typescripts`.
3. Compile `Typescripts` with source map.
4. Concat the result to the previously added `JavaScript`.
5. Uglify them.
6. Create the sorce map.
7. Save the result into some folder.

> **Update**
>
> Or just a way to make sure that the `TypeScript` is compiled before
>   proceeding with concatenating the result with `JavaScript`.

Comment: What is your problem? Is it the `output.js`? You could create 2 tasks, one requiring the other.

Comment: Yes but I need to make sure that the `TypeScript` is compiled before proceeding with concatenating the result with `JavaScript`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm more a `coffeescript` guy, but what about splitting into two separate tasks (solution below not tested, and there is a temporary output to the `./tmp` folder):

```
gulp.task('ts', function () {
    gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            out: 'output.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/ts'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['ts'], function() {
    gulp.src(['vendor/**/*.js', './tmp/ts/output.js'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Usage (in your terminal):

```
gulp default
```

Gulp will first run the `ts` task, then, once completed, it will run the `default` task

Comment: That is great but how to make sure that the `TypeScript` source is available when debugging?

Comment: How is that available to you in your current workflow?

Comment: Thanks, I used the hint `gulp.task('default', ['ts'], function() {})` and now I made something that would work. I did not test it very well but it works for now. so thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

If you require the `event-stream` package from npm, then you can do this:

```
var merge = require('event-stream').merge;

gulp.task('default', function() {
    var js = gulp.src('vendor/**/*.js');

    var ts = gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            out: 'output.js'
        }));

    return merge(js, ts)
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

I don't know off the top of my head how to source maps work but I'm sure it's easy to figure out.

Comment: I used your general approach, but used the stream-series package instead.