# Building Typescript for Angular using Gulp

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

I'm trying to setup an angularjs project according to [Johnpapa's Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) whilst using TypeScript and Gulp as a build tool. I believe Gulp is currently recommended over Grunt but I'm not very experienced with Gulp.

#### What I have:

My project currently looks like this:

```
src/
   +- ts/        # contains .ts source files
   +- typings/   # contains .d.ts typing definitions
   +- html/      # contains .html files
dist/
   +- bundle.js  # single .js file containing compiled typescript and sourcemaps
```

Following the angular style guide I have created a separate `.ts` file for each angular element.

```
my-app.module.ts
----------------

angular.module('myApp', []);
```

for initialization of the module and another for a simple implementation of a controller:

```
my-controller.controller.ts
----------------------------

export class MyController {
    testString = 'test';
}

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);
```

typescript is configured using a simple `tsconfig.json`. (Note that filesGlob is not active yet - it will become available from TypeScript 2.0)

```
tsconfig.json
-------------

{
  "exclude" : [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "filesGlob" : [
    "./src/typings/index.d.ts",
    "./src/ts/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap" : true,
    "outFile" : "./dist/bundle.js",
    "removeComments": false
  }
}
```

#### What I want:

I would ideally like to

- Have Gulp monitor new or updated `.ts` files in `./src/ts/**/*.ts`
- Concatenate all the files from `./src/ts/**/*.ts`. This is required for angular to work properly. Other methods I've tried using requirejs or browserify can't find the other .ts files without having to manually input references to these files.
- Compile using the definitions from `tsconfig.json`. This would take into consideration the typings in `./src/typings/index.d.ts` (for external modules including 'angular'). Also sourcemaps.
- Possibly an uglify or babelify step to finish it.

#### What I tried:

I've tried following the manual from the [typescriptlang handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html) but this uses browserify and won't work with angular.

Gulp-typescript also has a note on [concatenating files](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#concatenate-files) but the `out` option doesn't work like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src().pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This configuration will output an empty file with only comments.

Another method mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160066/using-gulp-how-to-first-compile-typescript-then-concatenate-the-result-and-uglif):

```
gulp.task('ts', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/ts/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            out: 'output.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/ts'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['ts'], function() {
    gulp.src(['./tmp/ts/output.js'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

But this gave two issues: 1. Even though I only pointed at the `.ts` files in `./src/ts` the typescript compiler started spewing errors from .ts in `./node_modules`. 2. It still didn't manage to concatenate everything.

I'm at quite a loss here. Can anyone help me set up this build script? I'm surprised I couldn't find a similar working demo anywhere.

## Solution:

I've configured the gulp environment based on the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38214928/557552) and **removed the 'export' statement for classes / objects that are not inside a typescript module**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that helps, here is a [Angular Typescript Gulp Tutorial](http://www.digistarters.com/2016/04/20/angular-typescript-gulp-project/) that has a basic TypeScript, Angular, Gulp, etc. setup that concatenate the app and the vendor/nodes files. There is the [demo code on github.](https://github.com/gregorifaroux/digiangularjs)

```
/* File: gulpfile.js */

// grab our gulp packages
var gulp  = require('gulp');
// Include plugins
var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', 'main-bower-files', 'del'],
    replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});

var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload      = browserSync.reload;


// create a default task to build the app
gulp.task('default', ['jade', 'typescript', 'bowerjs', 'bowercss', 'appcss'], function() {
  return plugins.util.log('App is built!')
});
```

In my example, we use Jade to HTML:

```
// Jade to HTML
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.jade')
        .pipe(plugins.jade()) // pip to jade plugin
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')) // tell gulp our output folder
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
        ;
});
```

For TypeScript, we compiled into one single app.js file:

```
// TYPESCRIPT to JavaScript
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(plugins.typescript({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            out: 'app.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
    ;
});
```

For bower, we merge all the js files in vendor.js and CSS in vendor.css:

```
// BOWER
gulp.task('bowerjs', function() {

    gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(plugins.filter('**/*.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.debug())
        .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

});

gulp.task('bowercss', function() {
    gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(plugins.filter('**/*.css'))
    .pipe(plugins.debug())
        .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

});
```

Custom CSS:

```
// APP css
gulp.task('appcss', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'))
        .pipe(reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

// CLEAN
gulp.task('clean', function(done) {
    var delconfig = [].concat(
        'dist',
        '.tmp/js'
    );

    // force: clean files outside current directory
    plugins.del(delconfig, {
        force: true
    }, done);
});
```

This is what reloads the browser when changes occur:

```
// Watch scss AND html files, doing different things with each.
gulp.task('serve', ['default'], function () {

    // Serve files from the root of this project
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./dist/"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("src/**/*.jade", ['jade']).on("change", reload);
    gulp.watch("src/**/*.ts", ['typescript']).on("change", reload);
        gulp.watch("src/**/*.css", ['appcss']).on("change", reload);
});
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this... I put the JS files that are automatically compiled from the text editor (Atom) into .tmp/js/atom ... some people put the .js in the same directory as the .ts but I find it confusing... less files is better for me:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": ".tmp/js/atom"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! This kind of demo was exactly what I was looking for. I adapted the gulpfile and the packages and gulp managed to build successfully. However the final app.js still only includes main.ts (even though the typescript task references src/**/*.ts). Do I have to declare a new angular module in every single .ts file for it to work properly?

Comment: Raven -- Yes, each .ts has it own module. It is the easiest. In your typescript task, add a .pipe(plugins.debug()) : gulp.task('typescript', function () {
 return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
   .pipe(plugins.debug())
  .pipe(plugins.typescript({
   noImplicitAny: true,
   out: 'app.js'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
    ;
});
And let me know how many items it returns and if it shows your different ts files.

Comment: I updated the github with the debug in the typescript task as it will be easier to read than the comment.

Comment: I've adjusted your code with a minimal example of my setup at [my fork here](https://github.com/Karasuni/digiangularjs/tree/issue1). It's possible that I'm doing something completely wrong with my references, but at least all files are being read. I used to have the behavior I describe by using reference path in every file, but that is very hard to maintain.

Comment: There is an error in your typescript when you do gulp typescript: my-controller-2.controller.ts: ERROR TS1005: ',' expected. Working on fixing the issues and I will let you know.

Comment: I removed the export from your controllers, typos in one of the controller, and index.html. I can't push to your branch... so, based on your code I created this: https://github.com/gregorifaroux/digi1.git

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I notice that I've made several severe mistakes (I blame the lack of my usual coding tools) in my example code but the major breakthrough was the removal of 'export' when the objects are not in a (typescript) module.

I went back and forth observing the effects small changes. It's starting to behave exactly as I was aiming for. Thanks again for all your help :D